# How can I join attributes by nearest, filtering the results by an another attribute present in both tables?

Tags: fields-attributes, attribute-joins, proximity

I have the centroid layer of climate polygons and I want to find the closest weather station of the same type of climate. The two layers (the one of centroids and the one of weather stations) contain a field with the type of climate. I am working with QGIS, the "Zanzibar 3.8" version.

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to specify the GIS software you are using and what you have attempted.

Comment: Sorry for the omission, I am using QGIS

Comment: Exact software, with release, and effort to date go in the body of the question. Please take the [Tour] to get a better idea of how we operate. Welcome to GIS SE.